# how to build a software with source code in linux?

Tags: python, build, configure

I am trying to install a software, a converter for FORTRAN77 to Fortran90, [fortran_tools](https://github.com/arktools/fortran_tools) ,I already cloned the source code into my local repository, then how to configure and build the software and make it run? I hope a series of procedures can be suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project appears to be pure python. So there is no compilation required to install it. As a python package, the installation procedure consists in making the sources available to your python interpreter. This can be done either by appending yourself the path or by using an installation script (called `setup.py`) provided by the package maintainer.

There is no `setup.py`so you cannot install it the usual way. If you want to be able to access the class from everywhere, you have to either append your path or create a setup file.

```
export PYTHONPATH=path_to_code:$PYTHONPATH
```

From there, follow the example in the test directory:

```
from fortran_tools import Fixed2Free
import os

path = '.'
filename = 'myfile_without_extension'

input_path = os.path.join(path, 'input', filename + '.f')
output_path = os.path.join(path, 'output', filename + '.f90')

Fixed2Free.from_argv(['', input_path, output_path, '--style'])
```

with `input_path` the path to the file you want to convert and `output_path` the path of the converted file.